# Firebase Stripe Extension: checkout button not redirecting to stripe live mode

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments

I am currently having issues integrating stripe onto my website. I've been working on this e-commerce site for a while now with the issue of stripe not responding to my checkout button when clicked. I made multiple attempts to contact stripe on this matter with the only useful information being that stripe.redirectToCheckout is deprecated. Also, I am trying to figure out how to use the firestore with the stripe extension. If someone could help me solve this problem it'll really be appreciated. I have attached my checkout.js(button function) and index.js(serverless function)

**checkout.js**

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "*****",
  authDomain: "*****",
  projectId: "*****",
  storageBucket: "*****",
  messagingSenderId: "*****",
  appId: "*****",
  measurementId: "*****"
};



 // Initialize Firebase
 const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
 const db = getFirestore(app);

 const checkoutButton = document.querySelector('#checkout-button')
 const createStripeCheckout = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('createStripeCheckout')
 const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.push)
  checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    createStripeCheckout()
       .then(response => {
         const sessionId = response.data.id
         stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: sessionId})
    })
 })
```

**index.js**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();


exports.createStripeCheckout = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {
  //stripe init
  const docRef = await db
    .collection("products")
    .doc(`${products.uid}`)
    .collection("checkout_sessions")
    .add({
      price: priceId,
      allow_promotion_codes: true,
      success_url: window.location.origin,
      cancel_url: window.location.origin,
    });

// Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
  onSnapshot(docRef, (snap) => {
    const data = snap.data();
    let error;
    let url;
    if (data) {
      error = data.error;
      url = data.url;
    }
    if (error) {
      // Show an error to your customer
      alert(`An error occurred: ${error.message}`);
    }
    if (url) {
      // We have a Stripe Checkout URL, let's redirect.
      window.location.assign(url);
    }
  });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!-- Shopping Cart -->
            <div class="cart-box">
                <div class="cart-icon">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-arrow-down"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="whole-cart-window hide">
                    <h2>Shopping Bag</h2>
                     <div class="cart-wrapper">
                         <!-- Item 1 -->
                </div> 
                <div class="subtotal">Subtotal: $0.00</div>
                <button type="submit" id="checkout-button">Checkout</button>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Each time I click the checkout button no action occurs but when wrapped around the  attribute it redirects with a 404 not found as a response. I am trying not to use the  attribute around the button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an expert in firebase extension but I noticed a couple of things here:

- As you mentioned `stripe.redirectToCheckout` is deprecated and shouldn't be used
- Also, you're handling the redirection in your `firebase` function when you call `window.location.assign(url)`

So I would start by removing the `.then` handler after `createStripeCheckout()` and see if this helps. You will end up with a code like this:

```
checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  createStripeCheckout()
})
```

If that doesn't help either I would highly recommend checking and getting inspired from this official [sample](https://github.com/stripe-samples/firebase-subscription-payments)

Comment: If I set the variable const = "stripe" how would I reuse it for the button though?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question